# how to sum particular column values page wise in gridview while printing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
sno name  salary

1    xx    10000

2    vv     5000

2    ss   25000

........
```

like this i have 100 records in gridview.
Now I want Print This gridview with 20 records per page and in footer i have to show sum of total salary in that page.

For example in bank statement we will get page wise sum of credit and debit balance like that.

I have a gridview with 100 records and A print button. When i click on print button,it is showing gridview in 5 pages. Now i want to sum particular column values in that page and show that sum value in a lable. similarly for all pages i want to sum page values.

Please any body help me in that way.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First you want to write code for finding 20 record and then write below code for sum of perticular column in gridview

```
public int total = 0;

 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
                    {  


                        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                        {
                            int qty = int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
                            total = total + qty;
                            TextBox1.Text = total.ToString();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: thank you for giving reply. but i need sum while clicking on print button

Comment: On  int qty = int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);  write your gridview index i.e which column value you want to print.

Comment: So write TextBox1.Text = total.ToString(); on print button click event and define total as public i.e  public int total = 0;

Comment: @PradnyaBolli good one but Instead of commenting you can update the answer..:)